# How do I remove the code on column specification in R Markdown while preserving code output

Tags: r, r-markdown

Simple question: I would like my RMarkdown to display my code in setting the "forrestfires" data set but I do not want to include the output on column parsing specification.

[image: RMarkdown]

Comment: Just a heads up.  Your assignment says to use `read.csv`, you are using `read_csv` from the `readr` package.    If you really want, you can use `capture.output(....)` but that might be overkill

Comment: Try this in your code chunk: `{r echo=TRUE, results='hide'}`

Comment: @avid_useR no dice

Comment: Can you elaborate? What happens if you use that specification? What about wrapping `suppressMessages` around `read_csv`?

Comment: Actually, I think `{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE}` would do it

Comment: @avid_useR oh nice yeah it did, had a typo. I was hoping to also use the same code to stop "Warning: built in x" to stop appearing in my output. Not nessesary, more of a prefereance Ive never been able to figure out.

Comment: `{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}` to also suppress warnings. This cheatsheet has all the answers: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In your code chunk, use `echo=TRUE` to display the code, `message=FALSE` to suppress messages, and `warning=FALSE` to suppress warnings:

````
```{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(readr)
mtcars <- read_csv("https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/raw/master/inst/extdata/mtcars.csv")
```
````

See [R Markdown Cheat Sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) for more options